# Why Do I get 404 (Page not found) for _some_ @@sharing dialogues in Plone 4.2.1?

Tags: plone

Hi All and thanks for reading.

I have two (out of 8) tabs, where I cannot successfully activate the "Save" button on the Sharing tab. Instead of an updated view of the Sharing-tab, if get at 404-page (Page not found). If I just open the Sharing-dialogue and do not change anything, I can press "Save", successfully, but if I activate any checkmark (e.g. "Logged-in users can view"), I get the mentioned error. (I tried this as me (msiegert) and as "admin".)

**Notice**: 
The members of "AG xxx" group who now lost the "can view" permissions still get the desired content within the "AG xxx" tab displayed in the site-search, but fail to open the result-link because of missing permissions - so "somewhere" it seems the permissions are not completely lost ...

**Background**:
I just migrated my Plone-3.2.1 Data.fs to Plone 4.2.1 (under Ubuntu-8) and I use the Intranet/Extranet-Workflow.
After upgrade was done I noticed that for some (!) of my "AG xxx" tabs, the Sharing entry for the group "AG xxx" vanished (as well as the access permissions). For most of the tabs I could manually recreate the "group 'AG xxx' has View and Edit permissions" entry. But for two tabs this fails with the error outlined above.

My httpd it apache2, which rewrites all (remaining) URLs as follows:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://bbc.mdc-berlin.de:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/bbc.mdc-berlin.de:80/bioinformatics/VirtualHostRoot/$1
```

The output of the apache-log for a failing and a successfull klick on "save" can be seen at http://pastie.org/6011725

I posted a series of screenshots illustrating the actions done to cause this 404-result on http://bbc.mdc-berlin.de/P4-sharing-error.html

[Edit 1]
There was no entry in the apache-error log, the entry in the apache-access log stayed same, but I picked from the "instance.log" ...

```
 2013-02-01T17:08:31 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1359734911.820.21161067649 http://bbc.mdc-berlin.de/ag-dieterich/@@sharing
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.workflow.browser.sharing, line 86, in __call__
  Module Products.Archetypes.CatalogMultiplex, line 73, in reindexObjectSecurity
  Module Products.ZCatalog.CatalogBrains, line 74, in _unrestrictedGetObject
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 300, in unrestrictedTraverse
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'launch')
NotFound: launch
```

Seems to have something to do with this "launch" parameter.

Comment: Go to your error log (in the control panel), and put a `#` comment before the `NotFound` error in the ignored errors list. Save. Trigger the 404 with the sharing tab again, then look at the error log and copy the traceback here in your post (you can [edit] it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least one stale object in your catalog that is breaking your sharing tab; please do a full reindex.

Via your control panel ('site setup'), go to the ZMI, locate the `portal_catlog` tool object, go to the "Advanced" tab. There, under "Catalog Maintenance" click on the "Update Catalog" button, and wait for a full reindex to complete.

Comment: Reindexing 125GB of Data.fs took 67 minutes. Afterwards I could set the @@haring as desired.